# Postgres regex to get single match

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a list of paths in Postgres:

`/approve/optimal/roadmap/`

`/approve/optimal/roadmap/payments/`

`/approve/optimal/roadmap/payments/benefits/`

`/approve/optimal/roadmap/payments/healthcare/`

I'd like a regex that will get the direct descendent of `/approve/optimal/roadmap/` (ie: `/approve/optimal/roadmap/payments/`, but nothing else)

I have looked at the `~` operator, but can't seem to make it work with POSIX regex.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE path ~ '/approve/optimal/roadmap/.+?/^.+/'`

If this is possible without regex, I'd love to implement THAT solution, as regex just gives me a headache.

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want to GET the value e.g. "payments", or do you want to get records WHERE path ~ ... ?

Comment: I would like the query to return records with the full path of direct descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path ~ '^/approve/optimal/roadmap/[^/]+/$'
```

[Try it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c4079/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.  Saved me from ingesting more Advil.